# NoMethodError in rails using multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nomethoderror

I can't seem to get the logic for my conditions to work for this query.  I can get @showemail = PreferenceSetting.find(1) to work...but when I try to add conditions, it keeps throwing a "NoMethodError".  I am fairly new at rails and am really stuck on this.

```
 def show
   @showemail = PreferenceSetting.where('user_id = ?', params[:u]).where('user_preference_id = ?', 1)
 end
```

This is my code for the view

```
 <%= @showemail.prefers %>
```

Every time I try to access the 'show' view it says "undefined method `prefers'.

My Models

```
class PreferenceSetting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users_preference,  inverse_of: :preference_settings
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :preference_settings
end
```

class UserPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :preference_settings,  inverse_of: :user_preference
    end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns an instance whereas your `where` methods return an ActiveRecord::Relation object.

Adjust the code of your `show` action like this:

```
def show
  conditions = {user_id: params[:u], user_preference_id: 1}
  @showemail = PreferenceSetting.where(conditions).last

  # you could also use: PreferenceSetting.find_by(conditions)
end
```

Comment: That worked & I'll accept it when it allows me...but why do I need to put "last" there is currently only one record in the development database.  It is the "first" and "last".

Comment: 'first' and 'last' will both work. But we need to specify one of them since otherwise a 'relation' object will be return by the `where`s. using 'first' will turn the relation into an array and then pick the value. But 'last' in this case will limit the query by 1 and just fetch what we want. you could also just use `find_by` instead of `where(conditions).last`